# Can I remove the second 'a' when asking "Is it a peach or a banana?" without changing the meaning?

Tags: grammar, questions

Is there any difference between asking

> Is it a peach or **a** banana?

vs.

> Is it a peach or banana?

The latter sounds to me like a yes/no question, while the prior does not. Is it just me?

Comment: It sounds odd without the second 'a' when the list occurs in a question.

Comment: This is a good question. I have to agree with you that the second sounds more like a yes/no question (even though I would probably still interpret it akin to *Is a peach or a banana what you're holding?* / *It's a banana.*).

Comment: It sounds that way to me as well. The first question seems to say "which one is it?", while the second one--"is it one of these two?".